# if $a_n\searrow, \geq 0$, then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum n(a_n-a_{n+1})$ converges simultaneously.

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $a_n\searrow, \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum n(a_n-a_{n+1})$ converges simultaneously.

If the assumption '$a_n$ decreases' is deleted, then it is not true. But how to construct such an example. I tried $a_n=1/n$ if $n=k^2$, and $a_n=0$ otherwise. But it does not work.

In other words, how to construct an example. $a_n$ tends to $0$, but for the two sereis $\sum a_n$ and $\sum n(a_n-a_{n+1})$, one converges, the other diverges.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I've never heard about the first claim before, concerning the simultaneous convergence. Does anyone know a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say your example with $$a_n = \begin{cases}1/n & \text{ if } n=k^2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ doesn't work?

---

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad\text{ converges} \\ k^2(a_{k^2}-a_{k^2+1}) = 1 \implies n(a_n-a_{n+1}) \not\to 0 \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(a_n-a_{n+1}) \text{ diverges}$$